# How to create a search algorithm for sales otimization in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, distance, traveling-salesman

I have a dataset with distances between 4 cities, each city has a sales store from the same company and I have the number of sales from the last month of each sales store in another dataset.

What i want to know is the best possible route between the cities to make more profit (each product is sold for 5) knowing that i only produce in the first city and then i have a truck with a maximum truckload of 5000 loading the other 3 cities.

I can´t find anything similar to my problem, the closest i could find were search algorithms, can someone tell me what approach to take?
Sorry if my question is a bit confusing.